# Looping using information from two files

Tags: unix, for-loop, awk, while-loop

I have two files, like this:
**file1**

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
name7
name8
name9
name10
name11
name12
name13
name14
name15
```

**file2**

```
name1   name1   3
name2   name1   4
name3   name1   2
name4   name1   1
name5   name1   5
name6   name1   3
name7   name1   7
name8   name1   6
name9   name1   7
name10  name1   5
name11  name1   9
name12  name1   5 
name13  name1   7
name14  name1   1
name15  name1   3
name1   name2   1
name2   name2   8
name3   name2   5
...
```

What I want to do is a loop that picks up the names in file1 and calculates the average of the top 10 highest values of colum 3 of file2 when the name catched appears in the first column of file2, desconsidering when the columns 1 and 2 are equal.

Desired output:
`name1 5.8 
name2 avg_value_top10
name3 avg_value_top10`

Using awk for one name will be like this:

```
awk '$1!="name1" && $2=="name1" {print}' file2 | sort -rn -k3 | head |  awk '{total+=$3} END {print $2,total/NR}' >> out
```

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: By *desconsidering* do you mean do not include lines where Col1==Col2?

Comment: Yes.  I don't want lines of file2 like: `name1 name1 0.2`

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a loop instead of all at once? [edit] your question to include sample input and expected output that more clearly (but concisely so use, say, 3 instead of 10) demonstrate your requirements. Use the editor's `{}` button to properly format your examples.

Comment: It doen't need to be a loop. It can be any kind of solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You posted 2 input files but no expected output yet. We need that too.

Comment: Sorry, I think that now is more clear.

Comment: Why do you have `name1 0.02158` when the two lines from your input with `line1` should be excluded because col1==col2? Shouldn't the example output be `name1  0.0091` with your example input?

Comment: The value 0.01431 (correct value) is the average of the top 10 highest values of column 3 for name1, not considering when col1 == col2.

Comment: Wait, you now say "top 10 highest values". Your question says "the first 10 values". Which is it? Update your question with your actual requirements.

Comment: _calculates the average of the first 10 values of colum 3 of file2 when the name catched appears in the first column of file2_: For `name1` in the first column of `file2` there are only 2 values: `0.091`(excluded because `$1==$2`) and `0.0091` (when `$2==name2`). How is the average `name1 0.01431`? Also, use better values and less values for one keyword but for more verifiable keywords. This one is a nightmare to understand.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it cleaner now. 
Is the average of the top 10 highest values of column 3 for each name in file1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk script calculates the average of highest 10 values in column or field 3 of `file2` excluding values where `$1==$2` for keywords in **field 2** that appear in `file1`. In the question you expect the names or keywords to appear in field 1 of `file2` but in that case the average for `name1` would be 1 as there are only two records with `name1` in field 1 of `file2` and the first one is excluded leaving only 1 for calculation. If you insist the keywords to be from field 1, change all references to `$2` with `$1` below.

`sort` is utilized for ordering `file2` on the third field to get the highest values for the average.

```
$ cat script.awk
NR==FNR {                            # read in file1
    a[$1]
    next
} 
($2 in a) && $1 != $2 && b[$2]<10 {  # the conditions
    b[$2]++                          # count of seen values
    a[$2]+=$3                        # summing the values
} 
END {                                # after getting the data
for(i in b)                          # for all good values
    print i, a[i]/b[i]               # calculate and print the average
}
```

Run:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1 <(sort -k3.1nr file2)
name1 5.8
name2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {names[$1]; next}
    $1 == $2 || !($2 in names) || count[$2] == 10 {next}
    {sum[$2] += $3; count[$2]++}
    END {
        for (name in sum)
            print name, sum[name]/count[name]
    }
' file1 file2
```

Given your sample data, this outputs

```
name1 0.01339
name2 0.12955
```

Comment: Yes, it's almost like that. Is it possible to make a `sort` to compute the average of the top 10 highest values of column 3?   Thanks

Comment: Maybe I can make like this:  

`sort -rn -k3 file2 | awk 'NR == FNR {names[$1]; next} $1 == $2 || !($2 in names) || count[$2] == 10 {next} {sum[$2] += $3; count[$2]++} END { for (name in sum) print name, sum[name]/count[name]}' file1 - `   

What you think?

Comment: @PeterSmith Hey, thanks for your help. Could you briefly explain me the mean of the || in the command?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {total[$1]=0; next} 
     $1==$2{next} 
       {c[$1]++; total[$1]+=$3} 
     END{ for (n in total)if (c[n]){print n, total[n]/c[n]}}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

If you want the top 10, then run the result of the `awk` through a `sort | head` pipe like so:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {total[$1]=0; next} 
     $1==$2{next} 
       { c[$1]++; total[$1]+=$3} 
     END{ for (n in total){ if (c[n]) print n, total[n]/c[n]}}' f1.txt f2.txt | sort -k2rn | head
```

Which for your example prints:

```
name3 0.13525
name7 0.0237
name4 0.0235
name8 0.019
name10 0.0151
name12 0.0115
name11 0.0091
name2 0.0091
name13 0.0077
name9 0.007
```

Comment: `It didn't work` is not very helpful. What did it do and how is that different than what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I tested again and was close.   The problem was that it printed just nine "names" (I have 166 in total) and the value was not the average of  the top 10 highest values.   Thanks.

Comment: So you want sorted output based on the average of Col3?

Comment: No, I need the average of the 10 highest values in column 3 for each name. Thanks